# What movie or television show contains a short clip of Radagast the Brown?

Tags: story-identification, tolkiens-legendarium

I was flipping through channels in the late 1990s and I came across an animated film or television show.  It immediately caught my eye, because it featured a wizard who I immediately recognized as Radagast.  Of course, I had never seen an animated Radagast, but this was a wizard robed in brown and animated in the style Rankin-Bass used for their versions of *The Hobbit* and *The Return of the King*.  A line of nuts was levitating past him, as he inspected each one.  (I think he found one that was unsatisfactory and kicked it out of line.)

Radagast went on dealing with the nuts for less than a minute.  Then there was a bit of narration, and it switched to some elves or fairies, animated in the completely different style.  I watched a little longer, but it did not seem very good, and I turned the television off after a few more minutes  My hypothesis about what I had seen was that they had taken some Rankin-Bass animation that never made it into a movie and inserted it into another story.  Does anybody know what I was watching?

Comment: Was it the [Ralph Bakshi version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(1978_film))?

Comment: The two Tolkien movies made by Rankin-Bass did not feature Radagast.

Comment: @Mooz:  I originally figured that it was probably leftover animation from Bakshi's film, but when I thought about it further, I decided that didn't quite make sense.  I think the style was closer to that used in The Hobbit.  And as I said in the question, this was footage that didn't make it into a final film.  Yet the animation was complete, and it looked good.  A discarded scene from Bakshi's film would probably have featured unfinished rotoscoping animation.

Comment: Why would a Radagast scene have been made for a Hobbit movie?

Comment: @ibid:  I have no idea, although putting him in the cartoon of The Return of the Kind doesn't make much more sense.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't the Seventh Doctor Who? :-P

Comment: After Googling "[rotoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping) wizard", I came across another Ralph Bakshi animated movie, called _[Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_(film))_. I haven't seen the movie, so can't confirm the nut inspection thing (I **will not** search for that!).

Comment: @Spencer No, it's not *Wizards*.

Comment: @Buzz I'm not convinced it's Radagast or anything to do with Tolkien.